# What is fedmsg?

Tags: linux, fedora

I would like, please, to read a simple explanation of what `fedmsg` is, what it does, why it is useful, and if it's not just something that runs quietly in the background, an introduction to how to start with it.

I am asking this question because, although there is an enormous amount of information available, it is couched in such technical terms and so full of jargon, that I find it impenetrable.

A confession; I have `fedmsg` installed on my Fedora 20 machine, but I can't remember why, or how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you have a question about a command on a Red Hat distro such as Fedora, CentOS, or RHEL it's best to utilize the package manager tools `rpm` or `yum`.

If the package isn't installed then use `yum` to see what it's about.

```
$ yum info <package name>
```

If it's already installed then you can also use `rpm`.

```
$ rpm -qi <package name>
```

#### Example

```
$ yum info fedmsg
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
Name        : fedmsg
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 0.7.7
Release     : 1.fc19
Size        : 465 k
Repo        : updates/19/x86_64
Summary     : Tools for Fedora Infrastructure real-time messaging
URL         : http://github.com/ralphbean/fedmsg
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : Python API used around Fedora Infrastructure to send and receive messages with
            : zeromq.  Includes some CLI tools.
```

If you have the name of an executable and aren't sure what package it's a part of you can use the command `repoquery`:

```
$ repoquery -qf </path/to/file>
```

#### Example

```
$ repoquery -qf */fedmsg
fedmsg-0:0.7.7-1.fc19.noarch
fedmsg-0:0.6.8-4.fc19.noarch
```

#### So what does it do?

The link that was posted in the comments to the [project's website](http://www.fedmsg.com/en/latest/) says it best:

> fedmsg (Fedora-Messaging) is a python package and API used around Fedora Infrastructure to send and receive messages to and from applications. See Overview for a thorough introduction.

#### So what does it *really* do?

If the technical jargon is too much to stomach then the bottom line is this.

> fedmsg is a project to provide a messaging bus that the various tools in the packaging toolchain can use to relay information to each other as to their states for various build/packaging related tasks.

Take Koji for example. Koji is Fedora's automated build system for compiling RPMs. Here's a screenshot:

[image: ss #1]

So as tasks are scheduled and built via Koji the state of where they are in the process is not easily exposed. The idea of fedmsg is to provide a messaging bus so that services like Koji can share the state of these activities with other systems within the packaging toolchain. Right now a maintainer of a package has to sit there and periodically check the web UI to see if a build has completed successfully.

The [overview page has a more detailed](http://www.fedmsg.com/en/latest/overview/) description of fedmsg if you want more info.

Comment: Thank you @sim, but I am afraid that the Overview you refer to is what I meant by "couched in such technical terms and so full of jargon, that I find it impenetrable". There are two kinds of answer to a question like this: those that allow the experts to nod wisely to one another, and those that make things clear to the naive enquirer. I was after the second one.

Comment: @HarryWeston - is that better?

Comment: Thank you @sim, yes that helps. I have followed up all the references I can,and get the feeling that fedmsg is something that runs in the background, easing package installation, but otherwise as a general user, I can just forget about it.

Comment: @HarryWeston It doesn't ease package installation. It's used in the Fedora _Project_ infrastructure so our different services can communicate to each other. For, every time a package is built, a message goes out saying who was responsible. One consumer of those messages is the [Fedora Badges](https://badges.fedoraproject.org/) system, where they are used to award the [If you build it...](https://badges.fedoraproject.org/badge/if-you-build-it...-koji-success-i) or [What goes up... (must come down)](https://badges.fedoraproject.org/badge/what-goes-up...-koji-failure-i) badges to deserving users.

Comment: If you want to create something that listens to this activity, because you want to make a service that reacts to it in some way, or if you want to [display statistics](http://thisweekinfedora.org/), you might want it installed, but otherwise, you really don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a central place for services to send and read messages about their events. Look at human-friendly interface at https://apps.fedoraproject.org/datagrepper/raw to get the idea.